# curl_easy_perform() failed: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: c++, libcurl

So I am using libcurl with C++ to retreive the data in a page, but for some reason it throws the error in the post title when I connect to my vps. The code in the vps just makes a get request and spits out some data from my database.

```
#include "requestMapper.hpp"

// Send a GET request to API to retreive image
void RequestMapper::retreiveData(std::string url) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        ISSUE HERE // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://104.236.200.91/index.php/food/");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
#ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
#endif
#ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
#endif
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

// Submit a post request to API link to send data
void RequestMapper::postData() {

}


int main(void) {
    RequestMapper rm;
    rm.retreiveData("sample");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine when the url is something like "https://google.com" but when I hit the link to my web server I set up I get that error. I am newer to this library, but I thought I was doing things correctly. if anyone has any insight please let me know! I'll continue to tinker with this and if I find a solution I'll share it here.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I recently solved this issue and wanted to share it with anyone who might stumble upon this post. 
I was using `https://URL` when instead I should have been using `http://URL` so if you run into this issue try using that instead first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's error 7, "couldn't connect to host" [described in the curl book](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html) like this:

> Failed to connect to host. curl managed to get an IP address to the
>   machine and it tried to setup a TCP connection to the host but failed.
>   This can be because you have specified the wrong port number, entered
>   the wrong host name, the wrong protocol or perhaps because there is a
>   firewall or another network equipment in between that blocks the
>   traffic from getting through.